# Oracle PL/SQL: Return true if column has at least "one null value" or "no data found"

Tags: oracle, plsql

How to return TRUE if column has at least one value as null OR no data found for any foreign key column value?
Tried searching for answers on the internet and could not find any with this combination. Hence posting it here.
Below is the data: Table name - **MY_EMP**

```
+----+------------+-----------+---------------------------+--------+
| id | first_name | last_name |           email           | fk_col |
+----+------------+-----------+---------------------------+--------+
|  1 | Hurleigh   | Stove     |                           |      1 |
|  2 | Joline     |           |                           |      1 |
|  3 | Martynne   | Honatsch  | mhonatsch2@infoseek.co.jp |      2 |
|  4 | Willyt     | Fullylove | wfullylove3@hhs.gov       |      2 |
|  5 | Joelly     |           | jferriday4@twitpic.com    |      3 |
+----+------------+-----------+---------------------------+--------+
```

- If last_name is null OR email is null for any fk_col then return true
- If last_name is null OR email is null for invalid fk_col then return true
- else return False

Tried to write function and was testing code. Here's the code which goes into function:

```
DECLARE
    v_verify NUMBER(2);
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT 1
    INTO   v_verify
    FROM   my_emp
    WHERE  ( last_name IS NULL
              OR email IS NULL )
           AND fk_col = :custom_fk;
    dbms_output.Put_line('Return True');
EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
      dbms_output.Put_line('Return False');
END;
```

When parameter :custom_fk = 1 then value returns TRUE (That is correct)
When parameter :custom_fk = 2 then value returns FALSE (That is correct)
When parameter :custom_fk = 700 then value returns FALSE (Incorrect as per my requirement) -- Here I want value to return true and unable to figure it out how to tweak code to match to my requirement.

Hope I get some help here.
Below is the code to create table and insert data:

```
/* CREATE TABLE */
CREATE TABLE MY_EMP(
id NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
first_name VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
last_name VARCHAR2(100),
email VARCHAR2(100),
fk_col NUMBER(5),
CONSTRAINT "MY_EMP_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
);

/*Insert data*/
INSERT INTO my_emp(id, first_name, last_name, email, fk_col)
VALUES(1, 'Hurleigh', 'Stove', '', 1);

INSERT INTO my_emp(id, first_name, last_name, email, fk_col)
VALUES(2, 'Joline', '', '', 1);

INSERT INTO my_emp(id, first_name, last_name, email, fk_col)
VALUES(3, 'Martynne', 'Honatsch', 'mhonatsch2@infoseek.co.jp', 2);

INSERT INTO my_emp(id, first_name, last_name, email, fk_col)
VALUES(4, 'Willyt', 'Fullylove', 'wfullylove3@hhs.gov', 2);

INSERT INTO my_emp(id, first_name, last_name, email, fk_col)
VALUES(5, 'Joelly', '', 'jferriday4@twitpic.com', 3);
```

Thanks,
Richa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this do?

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select count(*) cnt
  3     from (select distinct 1 as val
  4              from my_emp
  5              where fk_col = &&par_fk_col
  6                and (   last_name is null
  7                     or email is null
  8                    )
  9           union all
 10           select distinct 2
 11              from my_emp
 12              where fk_col = &&par_fk_col
 13          )
 14    )
 15  select case when cnt = 1 then 'false'
 16              else 'true'
 17         end as result
 18  from temp;
```

It results in

```
Enter value for par_fk_col: 1

RESUL
-----
true

SQL> undefine par_fk_col
SQL> /
Enter value for par_fk_col: 2

RESUL
-----
false

SQL> undefine par_fk_col
SQL> /
Enter value for par_fk_col: 3

RESUL
-----
true

SQL> undefine par_fk_col
SQL> /
Enter value for par_fk_col: 700

RESUL
-----
true

SQL>
```

That's all in one `select` statement. If you're writing a function, it is probably simpler to check whether `fk_col` exists in a separate query; if not, return `true` immediately. If so, then check for other conditions.

(BTW, thank you for test case. It is SO rare that I'm positively surprised!)

---

**[EDIT]** To "convert" that statement into PL/SQL isn't that difficult. Instead of an anonymous PL/SQL block, I'd suggest a **function**.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test (par_fk_col in my_emp.fk_col%type)
  2    return varchar2
  3  is
  4    retval varchar2(10);
  5  begin
  6    with temp as
  7       (select count(*) cnt
  8        from (select distinct 1 as val
  9                 from my_emp
 10                 where fk_col = par_fk_col
 11                   and (   last_name is null
 12                        or email is null
 13                       )
 14              union all
 15              select distinct 2
 16                 from my_emp
 17                 where fk_col = par_fk_col
 18             )
 19       )
 20     select case when cnt = 1 then 'false'
 21                 else 'true'
 22            end
 23     into retval
 24     from temp;
 25
 26     return retval;
 27  end;
 28  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select f_test(1) from dual;

F_TEST(1)
---------------------------------------
true

SQL> select f_test(2) from dual;

F_TEST(2)
---------------------------------------
false

SQL> select f_test(700) from dual;

F_TEST(700)
---------------------------------------
true

SQL>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your the help. Code is working fine if I run it as it is. It is resulting in error if I put this code inside function with par_fk_col as input argument. Unable to figure it out how to add this inside pl/sql block

Comment: You're welcome. I edited the answer and added a PL/SQL option. Have a look.

Comment: thank you again for your time and help. It worked. Earlier I was placing select into clause in different select statement. Now got it and understood the functionality. Greatly appreciate your help. Marking answer as solved.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT case when count(*)=1 then 'true' else 'false' end ret_value
from dual
where not exists(
   SELECT null
   FROM   my_emp
   WHERE  fk_col = :custom_fk
   having count(*)>0
      and count(*)=count(last_name) 
      and count(*)=count(email)
);
```

Example:

```sql
SQL> ho cat tests/2.sql
SELECT case when count(*)=1 then 'true' else 'false' end ret_value
from dual
where not exists(
   SELECT null
   FROM   my_emp
   WHERE  fk_col = &1
   having count(*)>0
      and count(*)=count(last_name)
      and count(*)=count(email)
);
SQL> @tests/2.sql 1

RET_V
-----
true

SQL> @tests/2.sql 2

RET_V
-----
false

SQL> @tests/2.sql 3

RET_V
-----
true

SQL> @tests/2.sql 700

RET_V
-----
true
```

Comment: thank you so much for the solution. If I run the code as it is, it is working fine. But if I run this query inside pl/sql block getting True for all the values. Below is the code:
declare
v_verify varchar(20);
begin
SELECT case when count(*)=1 then 'true' else 'false' end ret_value into v_verify
from dual
where not exists(
   SELECT null
   FROM   my_emp
   WHERE  fk_col = :custom_fk
   having count(*)>0
and count(*)=count(last_name) 
and count(*)=count(email)
);
dbms_output.put_line('Return True');
exception when no_data_found then
dbms_output.put_line('Return False');
end;

Comment: Just use `Dbms_output.put_line(v_verify) `. You don't need Exception handler there

Comment: Sure @Sayan Malakshinov. Now got it. Thanks for correcting me. Greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Converted your answer to function.
create or replace function myemp_test (fk_col_val in my_emp.fk_col%type)
   return varchar2
  is
  col_val varchar2(5);
  begin
SELECT case when count(*)=1 then 'true' else 'false' end ret_value into col_val
from dual
where not exists(
   SELECT null
   FROM   my_emp
   WHERE  fk_col = :custom_fk
   having count(*)>0
      and count(*)=count(last_name) 
      and count(*)=count(email)
);
return col_val;
--dbms_output.put_line(col_val);
end;